# Display dates in an order irrespective of which culture preference it is in

Tags: c#, .net, date, datetime

```
DateTimeFormatInfo us = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).DateTimeFormat;     
DateTimeFormatInfo cc = new CultureInfo(culturepreference, false).DateTimeFormat;
foreach (DataRow row in culturetable.Rows)
{
    DateTime dt = DateTime.Parse(row["date"].ToString()); 
    row["date"] = dt.ToString(cc.ShortDatePattern); 
}
```

I used above code to display dates as per culture preference. 
    **OUTPUT :
dates are out of order...

When Australia  en-AU culture preference is selected

```
1/09/2015
10/09/2015
11/09/2015
19/09/2015
2/09/2015
20/09/2015  
24/08/2015  
3/09/2015
30/08/2015
31/08/2015  
4/09/2015   
5/09/2015
```

When USA en-US is selected as culture preference we get below dates...

```
8/24/2015
8/30/2015   
8/31/2015   
9/1/2015    
9/10/2015   
9/11/2015       
9/19/2015
9/2/2015
9/20/2015
9/3/2015
9/4/2015
9/5/2015
```

***The dates displayed are not in sorted manner. I will need to display dates in an order irrespective of which culture preference it is in.

Comment: You're ordering dates as strings.  Instead keep the values as dates, then specify the format to display them as on the column.

Comment: What are you using to view the `DataTable`?  That's where the formatting should go.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Sort` property of the default view of your table. Make sure you use the `DefaultView` to access `DataRowView` instead of using the tables rows. Something like:

```
culturetable.DefaultView.Sort = "date ASC";

Console.WriteLine("==== en-AU ====");
DateTimeFormatInfo au = new CultureInfo("en-AU", false).DateTimeFormat;     
foreach(DataRowView row in culturetable.DefaultView){
    Console.WriteLine(((DateTime)row[0]).ToString(au.ShortDatePattern));
}
Console.WriteLine("==== en-US ====");
DateTimeFormatInfo us = new CultureInfo("en-US", false).DateTimeFormat;     
foreach(DataRowView row in culturetable.DefaultView){
    Console.WriteLine(((DateTime)row[0]).ToString(us.ShortDatePattern));
}
```

[Here is a fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3VHTVh)

Comment: I tried using culturetable.DefaultView.Sort = "date ASC" ... but still Its the same.. when I select "en-AU" preference I am getting 1/09/2015
10/09/2015
11/09/2015
19/09/2015
2/09/2015
20/09/2015  
24/08/2015  
3/09/2015
30/08/2015
31/08/2015  
4/09/2015   
5/09/2015

Comment: That's because you're still using the table's rows. Instead, you should be using the table's default view to access the `DataRowView`. I updated my answer with a full example and a fiddle. Notice that I used `foreach(DataRowView row in culturetable.DefaultView)` instead of `foreach (DataRow row in culturetable.Rows)`.

Comment: Thank you @Racil Hilan.. But It is not working as well.. May be because I am using devExpress.. I will be needing this sorting of date in the pivotgird as headers.....

Comment: What do you mean by not working? I've already provided you with a **fully working solution** in the [fiddle link](https://dotnetfiddle.net/3VHTVh). Have you checked that?

Comment: I have checked the fiddle link.. what I am trying to say is..if the solutions works for pivotgrid's ?? the dates which I am trying to sort are the header's of pivot grid..

Comment: I cannot tell without seeing the code. Update your question and post the code that you're using to bind your pivotgrids to the table. Remember that you will need to bind them to the default view of the `culturetable` table, not to the table itself.

Answer (score 0):

You are sorting the column as a string type after the column value has been converted from datetime type to string type. That is why you are seeing this issue. If you are not going to sort on a datetime type column, then add a hidden column and specify a custom "YYYYMMDD" string conversion for your datetime conversion to a string. Then sort on the hidden string column, and your data will always be correct regardless of your local culture display for the datatime value.

Comment: can you please elaborate...i never worked on hidden columns